# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main error in simple java program

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Trying to write a program to calculate my GPA for me, and I keep receiving this message when I try to run the prototype:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```

Here's the code:

package orange;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class plums{
    String philosophy, econ, french, fye, marine, stats;

    public void main(String args[]){
        Scanner gpa = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Philosophy Grade: ");
        philosophy = gpa.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Econ grade: ");
        econ = gpa.nextLine();
        System.out.println("French Grade: ");
        french = gpa.nextLine();
        System.out.println("FYE Grade: ");
        fye = gpa.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Marine grade: ");
        marine = gpa.nextLine();
        System.out.println("STATs Grade: ");
        stats = gpa.nextLine();

    }
        public void main(double[] args) {
            gpa philGrade = new gpa(4);

        if (philosophy.equals("a") ) 
            gpa.philGrade = 4;
            else if (philosophy.equals("a-"))
            gpa.philGrade = 3.7;
            else if (philosophy.equals("b+"))
                gpa.philGrade = 3.3;
            else if (philosophy.equals("b"))
                gpa.philGrade = 3;
            else if (philosophy.equals("b-"))
                gpa.philGrade = 2.7;
            else if (philosophy.equals("c+"))
                gpa.philGrade = 2.3;
            else if (philosophy.equals("c"))
                gpa.philGrade = 2;
            else if (philosophy.equals("c-"))
                gpa.philGrade = 1.7;
            else if (philosophy.equals("d+"))
                gpa.philGrade = 1.3;
            else if (philosophy.equals("d"))
                gpa.philGrade = 1;
            else if (philosophy.equals("d-"))
                gpa.philGrade = .7;
            else if (philosophy.equals("f"))
                gpa.philGrade = 0;
        else
            System.out.println("y u do dis??");
```

This is for one class and here's the other class:

```
package orange;

public class gpa {

public static double philGrade;
public gpa(double grade1){
    philGrade=grade1;
    }
public void lines(){
System.out.println(gpa.philGrade);


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` method must be declared as **public static**.

Declaration of **main** method:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
```

The `main` method is declared **public** as it called from outside, i.e by JVM.
And it is declared as **static** as it is called before the instantiation of object of class (it is the first point of execution of code.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
...
}
```

You are missing `static`

Answer (score 0):

Make the  main method static as shown below.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main(String[] args)` is the entry point for any Java program. When you execute a java file, JVM looks for this method to start execution. In your case, it is unable to find it and hence it throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main` error.

Solution:

Added `static` modifier to your method :  `public void main(String args[])`